# android:how to imageview move(Up-down) automatialy (by loop) without touch listener?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to move an image view up and down automatically without any touch event.  How can I implement it? Please give me suggestions.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks Tanmay Madal ...I want to moving the Image up-down as animation in screen by increement-decrement of positions but i cant get the possition of imageview.          Have you any Other Idea for Moving the Image ??